# fix error code 0 " Data not found or data repeated " in zkemkeeper.dll

Tags: c#, sql-server, dll, windows

I am trying to connect a device to my C#.net windows application . I want to connect this device to read data from it and store them into sqlserver database so I use zkemkeeper.dll to connect to device .but I get error .

code :

```
if (txtIP.Text.Trim() == "" || txtPort.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("IP and Port cannot be null", "Error");
                return;
            }
            int idwErrorCode = 0;
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            if (button1.Text == "DisConnect")
            {
                axCZKEM1.Disconnect();
                bIsConnected = false;
                button1.Text = "Connect";
                lblState.Text = "Current State:DisConnected";
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                return;
            }
            bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(txtIP.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
            if (bIsConnected == true)
            {
                button1.Text = "DisConnect";
                button1.Refresh();
                lblState.Text = "Current State:Connected";
                iMachineNumber = 1;
                axCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535);
            }
            else
            {
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect the device,ErrorCode=" + idwErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
            }
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }

    }
```

I get error code 0 " `Data not found or data repeated` " on this line

```
 bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(txtIP.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
```

Comment: Show us your p-invoke signature for `Connect_Net`

Comment: bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(txtIP.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));